# Fragment is trying to cast to activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I know this answer is probably simple but i cannot figure it out. I am modifying example code for a project and keep getting a ClassCastException when i try to launch the app. Says that ListActivityFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity. What im not understanding(which is probably the simple part) is why its trying to cast it onto an activity when my main is a fragmentactivity. I know the code is rough, still trying to finish it up but cant get past this.

FragmentActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private boolean isLargeScreen = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (findViewById(R.id.normal_screen_layout) != null) {
        isLargeScreen = false;
        ListActivityFragment listActivityFragment = new ListActivityFragment();
        listActivityFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.normal_screen_layout, listActivityFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.addItem:
        ListActivityFragment newFragment = new ListActivityFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.normal_screen_layout, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}

}




}
```

ListActivity

```
public class ListActivityFragment extends ListFragment implements
    OnClickListener {
private ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
private ListView listView;
private View outerView;
private Button deleteButton;
private ListActivityListener listener;

public interface ListActivityListener {
    public void meetingAdded();
}

public ListActivityFragment() {

}

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        listener = (ListActivityListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    outerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_meetings, container,
            false);
    listView = (ListView) outerView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    deleteButton = (Button) outerView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    createList();
    return outerView;
}

public void createList() {
    items.clear();
    Iterator<Items> iterator = ItemCollection.Instance().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        items.add(iterator.next().toString());
    }

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    ListView listView = getListView();
    for (int index = 0; index < listView.getChildCount(); index++) {
        View viewGroup = listView.getChildAt(index);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) viewGroup
                .findViewById(R.id.itemSelectCheckBox);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) viewGroup
                    .findViewById(R.id.productTextView);
            int key = (Integer) textView.getTag();
            ItemCollection.Instance().delete(key);
        }
    }
    createList();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
}
```

And heres the Logcat

```
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878): Process: com.example.assignment5, PID: 878
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to        instantiate activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.assignment5/com.example.assignment5.ListActivityFragment}:    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.assignment5.ListActivityFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.assignment5.ListActivityFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  ... 11 more
07-15 01:59:51.160: E/NetdConnector(383): NDC Command {65 bandwidth setiquota eth0 9223372036854775807} took too long (1117ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.assignment5.ListActivityFragment cannot be cast to
>   android.app.Activity 07-15 01:59:50.710: E/AndroidRuntime(878):

As the error says -

*`ListActivityFragment` is not an activity. So you are trying to access it just like an activity.*

*Make sure you haven't declared `ListActivityFragment` in the manifest. In your manifest if you made an entry for the fragment then that's wrong.*

*Also make sure that you haven't used `startActivity` for the fragment. Because this is done for activity class and not for fragment class.*

Comment: Looks like you were right on. ListActivityFragment was in my manifest for some reason, probably mistakenly put it there. Thanks for the help!